# How to say please could I have my money back?

Tags: words, conversations

I paid for some lessons in advance but now it looks like I won't be able to do them all. So I want to tell the teacher to give me my money back (in a polite way).

My ideas are something like either お金を返して下さい　or お金を戻して下さい but I don't know if it's correct and polite.

How do I say

> Please give me my money back

in a polite way?

Comment: More than just saying this, you're gonna need to humbly and politely give a reason why you can't take the lessons.

Comment: お金を返してください is indeed a request for giving the money back,

Answer (score 4):

> 返金{へんきん}して頂{いただ}けますでしょうか？

Is a very polite way of asking for a refund.